# Linq to Entities, checking for specific foreign key id?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to get rows where the foreign key ParentID == 0, and this is what I am trying but I get a NotSupportedException because it can't translate the ArrayIndex `[0]`:

```
IQueryable<ApplicationSectionNode> topLevelNodeQuery =
    from n in uacEntitiesContext.ApplicationSectionNodeSet
    where (int)n.Parent.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value == 0
    orderby n.Sequence
    select n;
```

So I need to pull that ArrayIndex out of the query so that the runtime can successfully translate the query.  I'm not sure how to do that though.  How does one query a specific object via it's primary key or set of objects via foreign key?

Edit:  Note that there is not actually a row in the table with NodeId == 0, the 0 is a magic value(not my idea) to indicate top level nodes.  So I can't do n.Parent.NodeId == 0

Comment: Have you tried "where n.Parent == null"?

Comment: @Mattias that actually works.  I didn't think it would because the people who made the database used a value of 0 instead of null.  Post this as an answer please and I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `where n.Parent == null`. The reason that works is that EF can't find any row with the ID of 0 in the database, so instead it sets the property to null (and you can query it in the same manner).

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
IQueryable<ApplicationSectionNode> topLevelNodeQuery =
from n in uacEntitiesContext.ApplicationSectionNodeSet
where (int)n.Parent.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.First().Value == 0
orderby n.Sequence
select n;
```

Comment: Nice try.  I tried similar variations.  Your code produces a new NotSupportedException message: The specified type member 'EntityKey' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.